# How to use jumbotron font awesome icons to be big as the ones on the fa website

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, icons, font-awesome

On the Font Awesome website they always show few sizes of the icons, like here:
http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/server/
... and these icons get the sizes way bigger than the regular fa-Xx range.

From what I can see they use .jumbotron css class and .jumbotron-icon for the container and the size is set by i.e. fa-6 (without any "x" after the number). I was trying to apply this by making the container of class "jumbotron jumbotron-icon", but it does not work.

The website is based on Bootstrap.

Shall it be something like?

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-icon">
  <div class="someContainerWhereTheFaIconResides">
    <i class="fa fa-server fa-6"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would be thankful for an idea how it shall be implemented.

Answer (score 4):

The font size is not done with any built in classes from Bootstrap or Font-Awesome (The class `fa-6` is **not** implemented in **Font Awesome**.) You'll need to write and apply your own. If you inspect the page you'll see how this is being acheived.

See example Snippet.

```css
.jumbotron-icon .fa-6 {
  font-size: 20em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-icon">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="info-icons">
      <i class="fa fa-server fa-6"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```